# Restful API inside of Vue.js or Nuxt locally

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm building a website using `vue.js` and `nuxt` and have built a fake API using an `npm` json-server, until the other part of my team builds out the proper API for it.

I'm using `Axios` for get requests to get my endpoints and my website has a product page and a detail page  information that needs to be served via the API.

I've now just been told that the API is not coming and if it is will be a long time away, so I'm having to move my product json files inside of the `vue.js` application.

I've now created my product.json file inside of the static folder and i'm still using Axios to get the json file from this location rather than Cross Domain via the API which is fine.

However, now I need to access the detail pages and pass the unique ID of the products and cannot do so because iv'e lost the restfulness of the API.

```
http://mydomain/products/uniqueID
```

Is there a way I can simulate and serve restful json files inside of my vue.js application as now I can't see how I can access my detail pages?

Comment: It's going to be deployed to a staging website, so I can't serve the json-server locally

Answer (score 0):

You could use Postman as a mock server.

https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/mock-servers/setting-up-mock/

Comment: I've update my question. I don't need a mock server or simulate. I need an API inside of my vue.js application